# Literal '_' in prolog?

Tags: prolog

Is there a way to unify to the quoted atom `'_'` as the literal underscore? Or does Prolog still treat this as the anonymous variable? I cannot for the life of me get a `functor(['_'])` to fire even if I type that exact phrase into the prolog prompt.

This is part of a larger program where I'm taking a string input as a list of ASCII codes, then to a list of atoms, and finally trying to do some list processing on that. I'm currently using the combo of `read_line_to_codes/2, name/2 atom_chars/2.` to obtain that list of atoms.

Please excuse any improper terminology; I'm new to Prolog.

Comment: That is a literal underscore. However, you're reading codes, not chars, so you probably want 95 instead.

Comment: To underscore (no pun intended) what Daniel said: `atom_codes('_', C).` results in `C = [95]`. `atom_chars/2` just breaks an atom up into a list of single-character atoms, not atom character codes.